# How to create a Table with same structure from MySQL in SQL server Using Store Procedure or SSIS Functionality

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have some list of Tables to be created in SQL Server with the same structure as they are currently present in MySQL DB.

Tools which i can use are SSIS , SQL Server (T-SQL) But haven't found a solution still

Comment: Here is a round about way.  But it outside your current list of "tools".  Run the "Reverse Poco Generator" : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator  This will give you POCO items (originating from MySql).   Then you change the "concrete" EntityFramework to point to MsSqlServer, and run a "EnsureCreated" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-6.0

Comment: You only need to create a table once so neither SSIS nor stored procedures are useful. You can use [SQL Serve Migration Assistant for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-ver16) to convert tables, types, triggers etc. The tool will analyze the MySQL tables, highlight any conversion problems and offer fixes.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis.  I did not know about that one.